# about "most likely" in "It identifies those most likely to get ahead and to be more successful in their working careers."

Tags: adverbs

Does *most likely* within:

> It identifies those **most likely** to get ahead and to be more successful in their working careers.

modify *those* or *to get ahead* ? In other words, does the sentence above mean:

> It identifies those **who are the most likely** to get ahead and to be more successful in their working careers.

or:

> It identifies those **very likely** to get ahead and to be more successful in their working careers.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*likely* modifies *those*; *most* modifies *likely*; *to get ahead…* depends on *likely*, so *likely* cannot modify it.  Your two paraphrases are nearly equivalent in meaning.

Comment: "to get ahead… depends on likely," **to get ahead** doesn't depend upon likely, **most likely** could be removed from the sentence and it would still be meaningful :"It identifies those to get ahead and to be more successful in their working careers." = "It identifies those who will get ahead and be more successful in their working careers.". Also, my two paraphrases express different meanings, the first describes the **most likely** (likeliest) from a given set of people whereas the second describes those who are just **very likely**, the first case is a subset of the second.